# Onclick Mostrar texto

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un piano interactivo el cual reproduce los sonidos mediante un onclick, me gustaría saber como puedo mostrar las notas que va pulsando el usuario en un campo de texto con javascript.

Esta es la función con la que reproduzco los sonidos:

```
$(document).ready(function()) {

        var sonido = document.getElementById("sonido");
        var sonido2 = document.getElementById("sonido2");
        var sonido3 = document.getElementById("sonido3");
        var sonido4 = document.getElementById("sonido4");
        var sonido5 = document.getElementById("sonido5");
        var sonido6 = document.getElementById("sonido6");
        var sonido7 = document.getElementById("sonido7");
        var sonido8 = document.getElementById("sonido8");
        var sonido9 = document.getElementById("sonido9");
        var sonido10 = document.getElementById("sonido10");
        var sonido11 = document.getElementById("sonido11");
        var sonido12 = document.getElementById("sonido12");
        var sonido13 = document.getElementById("sonido13");
        var sonido14 = document.getElementById("sonido14");
        var sonido15 = document.getElementById("sonido15");
        var sonido16 = document.getElementById("sonido16");
        var sonido17 = document.getElementById("sonido17");
        var sonido18 = document.getElementById("sonido18");
        var sonido19 = document.getElementById("sonido19");
        var sonido20 = document.getElementById("sonido20");
        var sonido21 = document.getElementById("sonido21");
        var sonido22 = document.getElementById("sonido22");
        var sonido23 = document.getElementById("sonido23");
        var sonido24 = document.getElementById("sonido24");
        var sonido25 = document.getElementById("sonido25");
        var sonido26 = document.getElementById("sonido26");

    }
```

Comment: No creo realmente que tu código de arriba reproduzca sonidos. Simplemente estás cogiendo elementos de tu documento. Pon algo más de tu código, como por ejemplo que es lo que haces al hacer click para reproducir los sonidos.

Comment: El sonido lo coge de esta id:                                                                   <audio id="sonido">
    <source src="midia/220-A%20(mp3cut.net).mp3">
</audio>.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que he entendido, lo he entendido bien, podrías usar esto:

```
document.getElementById("idCampoTexto").innerHTML = document.getElementById("idCampoTexto").innerText + nota;
```

Siendo `nota` una variable en la que tienes el valor de la nota en String.

Con este código irá añadiendo las notas al cuadro de texto, ahora ya puedes ir jugando con el formato a la hora de hacer el innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

Puedes especificar el contenido que quieras en un elemento del DOM mediante el atributo `innerHTML`, por ejemplo, si tienes un elemento con `id="nota"` y la nota almacenada en una variable `nota`:

```
document.getElementById("nota").innerHTML = nota;
```